# If $\gcd(m,n)= 1$ and $n \leq km$ and $m \leq kn$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(m,n)= 1$ and $n \leq km$ and $m \leq kn$

I want to prove that $ mn \leq k$

If I multiply the first inequality by $m$ I will get that $mn \leq km^2$

And If I multiply the second inequality by $n$ I will get that $mn \leq kn^2$

But that How to deduce that $mn \leq k$.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde what if $k \neq 1$ ?

Comment: what if you have $k=7,m=3,n=2$ then we have $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and we also have that $m \leq kn$ and $n \leq km$  so it's not impossible as u said !! @DietrichBurde

Comment: Well, one of the inequalities in redundant as we can take $m \geq n$ without loss of generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true in general. Take $k=2$, $n=11$ and $m=13$. Then

$$11 \leq 2 \cdot 13$$
$$13 \leq 2 \cdot 11$$
$$\gcd(11,13) = 1$$

but

$$nm = 11\cdot 13 \geq 2 = k$$